# Dynamic Theming Ionic- not working for model view

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Im used  this https://devdactic.com/dynamic-theming-ionic/ for  my university project app ,Theme background change are working but  ihave some issue, (**theme.dark not work**)  Ionic [Modals](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals)  for not working theme option , other pages are working , How to fix that issue
Thanks

**my-code**

**providers - settings.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class SettingsProvider {

  private theme: BehaviorSubject<String>;

  constructor() {
    this.theme = new BehaviorSubject('dark-light');



  }
  setActiveTheme(val) {
    this.theme.next(val);
  }

  getActiveTheme() {
    return this.theme.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**page/setting.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <p text-center>Theme settings</p>
  <button ion-button full icon-left (click)="toggleAppTheme()" (click)="presentLoading()" style="background: lightgrey;color: #263447;">
    <ion-icon  name="sunny"></ion-icon>Light
  </button>

 <button ion-button full icon-left (click)="toggleAppThemes()" (click)="presentLoading()" style="background: #263447;color: white;">
    <ion-icon  name="bulb"></ion-icon>Dark
  </button>
</ion-content>
```

**setting.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams , LoadingController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {SettingsProvider} from "../../providers/settings/settings";


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-settings',
  templateUrl: 'settings.html',
})
export class SettingsPage {
  selectedTheme: String;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private settings: SettingsProvider,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    this.settings.getActiveTheme().subscribe(val => this.selectedTheme = val);

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SettingsPage');
  }
  to

  toggleAppTheme() {

      this.settings.setActiveTheme('light-theme');

  }
  toggleAppThemes() {
 this.settings.setActiveTheme('dark-theme');

  }
}
```

app.html

```
ion-menu  id="myMenu" [content]="content" side="right" persistent="true">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-grid>

        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-6>
            <div text-left  style="color: #000000; font-size: 2rem;">
       Car-Rent</div>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col >
            <div  class="t-setting" style="text-align: right;font-size: 2rem; color:#a57958;" ><ion-icon ios="ios-settings-outline" md="md-settings"></ion-icon></div>

            </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <div  class="t-logout" style="font-size: 2rem; color:#a57958; text-indent: 0rem;  text-align: right;"  ><ion-icon ios="ios-log-out" md="md-log-out"></ion-icon></div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>




    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content >
    <ion-list >
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages"[class.activeHighlight]="checkActive(p)" (click)="openPage(p)" > <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" item-left></ion-icon>{{p.title}}</button>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"  [class]="selectedTheme" ></ion-nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because you haven't wrote css for **Models**.

As I can see they asking you to theme your app,

```
.dark-theme {
  ion-content {
    background-color: #090f2f;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .toolbar-title {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .header .toolbar-background {
    border-color: #ff0fff;
    background-color: #090f2f;
  }  
      // Define model customization scss here
      ion-modal ion-content{
         background-color:#000;
      }
 }
```

So it should work fine.
if it is still not working add **:host /deep/** and it should work like a charm.

```
:host /deep/ ion-modal ion-content{
   background-color:#000;
}
```

Comment: sir my issue is theme dark option, still not working :(

Comment: @core114 bro I have updated the code and paste it to your dark theme and see if it works? if not and the **:host /deep/** part as I mentioned below. also if you are using ion-list inside model. please remember it has a white color background.

Comment: Sir ,Your code are work for  other pages , but not work for the `modals` https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#modals

Comment: Did you add **:host /deep/ ion-modal ion-content{
   background-color:#000;
}** to your theme?

Comment: Sir it's correct ? `page-modal {
  .dark-theme {
    ion-content {
      background-color: #090f2f;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .toolbar-title {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .header .toolbar-background {
      border-color: #ff0fff;
      background-color: #090f2f;
    }
    // Define model customization scss here
    ion-modal ion-content{
      background-color:#000;
    }
  }}`

Comment: No its not. you have inserted it into the page-model page scss file. you have to add the line of code into theme file. any way run ionic serve and use chrome inspector to the model. and define some custom css so you could see the change. and use that code to work with the theme.scss

Answer (score 2):

Could you try to alterate setting.ts file:

from

```
toggleAppTheme() {
 this.settings.setActiveTheme('light-theme');
}
toggleAppThemes() {
 this.settings.setActiveTheme('dark-theme');
}
```

to

```
toggleAppTheme() {
if (this.selectedTheme === 'dark-theme') {
   this.settings.setActiveTheme('light-theme');
} else {
   this.settings.setActiveTheme('dark-theme');
}
```

I note also a "**s**" at the end of the second occurence of `toggleAppThemes()` in your setting, the func with the "s" is not existing... so please change to `toggleAppTheme()`

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the trick**

- Set your selected Theme to cssClass of modal.
- Set Active Theme inside a global variable ->>

Eg. in provider declare a variable ->> Theme:any=“light-theme”;

and when we toggleAppTheme we need to change this variable with the active theme

`this.modal.create(“CustomeModal”, {param: “test”}, {
cssClass: provide.yourTheme
});`

Cool thanks for the above answer, Is there a way I can change it for Popovers as well?? 
[Link to the html code for reference, If you see the yellow-theme does not get added to the popover div's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThZb2.png)

Comment: yes is the same way like the modal the popovers has cssClass this an exmple: let popover = this.popover.create(YourPopover, {}, {cssClass: 'yourClass'})